# Android micro thumbnail query empty

Tags: android, image, sqlite, uri, thumbnails

Why does this query return 0 results?

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                       MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                       null,
                       MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + " = " 
                       + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                       null, null);
```

If `MICRO_KIND` is replaced with `MINI_KIND`, I get about as many rows as I have images on my device.

Also, why doesn't the thumbnails table contain the THUMB_DATA column (which should hold the micro thumb blob)? Is Android documentation fact or fiction?